Partial reversal in stripe connect
I have created payment intent with a charge of 3150 and transfered 2850 to connect account. Now i am creating refund of 3000. When I create refund and reverse transfer it create reversal also with partial proportion of amount refund. For example I charged 3150 and transfered 2850 now i am refunding 3000 out of 3150 so stripe is reversing 2714.29 from connect account. Is there a way to reverse total amount transfered using refund api or do I need to create transfer seperately and then create refund.
Thank in advance.

If you use Separate Charges and Transfers integration, you should make additional transfer reversal to reverse the fund from connected account to platform. This can't be done in the refund API.
